# Using only Two gear but openshift show Three gear in use

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge, openshift-gears

I had two application both with 1 small gear (total 2 small gear).

Recently I tried to  add another application with one small gear. As a free user I am allowed to use only 3 great in total.

When creating this new application I faced some issues and application was not created successfully. But openshift shows the remaining gear  is now occupied. So I cannot retry to create my 3rd app.

Current situation is, Two application both with one gear, But used gear Three. Is there any way to fix this now.

Comment: how did you create the gear? through`rhc` or through the online web console?

Comment: through online web with tomcal 7 cartridges.

Comment: Use the contact form here https://developers.openshift.com/contact.html , make sure to include your OpenShift username and we'll get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have your own OpenShift V2 environment? If so, this sounds like an opportunity to ping your site admin or support team for help.

Red Hat is no longer offering a publicly-hosted "OpenShift V2" environment (using "gears", as you have described).  Please sign up for a new OpenShift "V3" account, or start your own local cluster with MiniShift.